# $\arccos(i)=z$ (Complex Variables)

Tags: complex-analysis

Working through the Schaum's Complex variables outline. In problem 79 of chapter 2, I just do not know how this answer was obtained. I can get one answer using the famous formula for inverse cosine of a complex variable, but they have a second answer which is:$$2k\pi +\frac{3\pi}2 -i\ln(\sqrt{2}-1) $$

Please Help

Comment: i believe the question is in the title. find $\arccos (i)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suppose $\arccos(i) = z,$ then $\cos z = \cos(x + iy) = \cos x \cosh y + i \sin x \sin h y = i  $  we get two equations 
$$ \cos x \cosh y = 0, \sin x \sinh y = 1$$ solutions are $x = \pm \pi/2 + 2k\pi$  and $ \sinh y = \pm 1$ solving $\sinh y = \pm 1$ you get $y = \ln(1+\sqrt 2), \ln(\sqrt 2 - 1)$  altogether you have $$x = \pm \pi /2 + 2k\pi, y = \ln(\sqrt 2 \pm 1)$$

Comment: Thanks for the response , but I still do not get how 3pi/2 was obtained in Schaum's , your answer only contains pi/2.

Comment: But, $-\pi/2+2\pi = 3\pi/2$. I think his answer has $3\pi/2$ and much much more...

Comment: Hi Mr Cook Thanks for your response ...I can see that his answer has 3pi/2 , but then my question is why does the book give 2 distinct answers : One is -iln(root2+1)+pi/2+2kpi (which is exactly what I got working on the problem) ;But the second one is -iln(root2-1)+3pi/2+2kpi,by the above reasoning second answer is contained in first ?? or is it??

Comment: Those two answers are implicit within his $\pm$ on the $\pi/2$. The $+$ gives your answer, the $-$ gives the $3\pi/2$. This is typical of a trig. equation, we tend to get two sequences of answers which are separated by $2\pi$. Graphically, it's not too hard to visualize in the real case. Think about a horizontal line intersecting a sinusoidal graph. It hits the wave the same two spots every cycle...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response , I can clearly see now what the solver did to arrive at his solution ,I am studying Complex by myself and the subject is more difficult than it looks at first glance.......In the Schaum's book they actually had a formula for this inverse cosine ...My question now is why I cannot get these 2 answers using this formula (which I believe was the intention of this chapter)...The formula is ArccosZ=-iln(z+root(zsquared-1)) ...I only get one part of the answer with this formula...

Comment: @abel Shoudn't the identity be $\cos(x + iy) = \cos x \cosh y - i \sin x \sinh y$?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding herashefat's final comment, I wanted to post this to see what everyone thinks. Referencing herashefat's last comment pertaining to the solution above, "My question now is why I cannot get these 2 answers using this formula (which I believe was the intention of this chapter)...The formula is ArccosZ=-iln(z+root(zsquared-1))."

In other words, herashefat is asking how to get both solutions from the formula

> $\cos^{-1}(z)=-i\log\big(z+(z^{2}-1)^{^{\frac{1}{2}}}\big)$.

This formula is in my book as well (I'm currently studying for an exam, and this very same problem arose as a practice problem...hence the reason why I wanted to post a solution); the book is by Edward Saff, $Fundamentals~of~Complex~Analysis,$ 3rd Ed. -- see PG.135.

Here's what I did...

$\cos^{-1}(z)=-i\log\big(i+(i^{2}-1)^{^{\frac{1}{2}}}\big)$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~ = -i\log\big(i+(i^{2}-1)^{^{\frac{1}{2}}}\big)$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~ = -i\log\big(i+(-2)^{^{\frac{1}{2}}}\big)$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~ = -i\log\big(i\pm\sqrt{2}i\big)$  $~~~~~~~~~~~~$[[ Recalling both, distinct, square roots of $-2$ ]]

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~ = -i\bigg[\text{Log}\big(\big|i\big(1\pm\sqrt{2}\big)\big|\big)+i\big[\text{Arg}\big[i\big(1\pm\sqrt{2}\big)+2k\pi\big]\bigg]$, $~~$for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~ = -i\bigg[\text{Log}\big(\sqrt{3\pm 2\sqrt{2}}\big)+i\big(\pm\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\big)\bigg]$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~ = \pm\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi-i~~\!\!\text{Log}\big(\sqrt{3\pm 2\sqrt{2}}\big)$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~ = \pm\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi+i~~\!\!\text{Log}\bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3\pm 2\sqrt{2}}}\bigg)$.

Note, the capitalized "$\text{Log}$" signifies the real (single-valued) logarithmic function (as opposed to the complex, multi-valued, logarithmic function). Furthermore, in the sixth equality above, taking the absolute value of $i\big(1\pm\sqrt(2)\big)$ within the argument for the real logarithm, I carried out squaring the irrational numbers $1\pm\sqrt{2}$ within the overall square root, as opposed to the square root and the squared term canceling out, because we will end up with the $\text{Log}\big(1\pm\sqrt{2}\big)$, and the minus part is undefined (as $1-\sqrt{2}<0$). This gives different solutions compared to what the OP had asked and the solutions above; but, in light of herashefat's comment, we have two solutions as a result of (or driven out by) using the formula he specified that is referenced above in my solution (I'm guessing there may be some algebraic simplification that we can use to make everything look more familiar to the solutions above...maybe I'm wrong).

Overall, I want to see what everyone thinks in the process. Also, the $\pm$ within the $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ term may be unnecessary since the operation here is $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$, for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$; overall, I hope I didn't make a wrong move somewhere.